# Problem with Display of jQuery Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Menu does not display in line. Not sure how to call the CSS code. Also I want the alert to tell me which menu item was clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_list() {
   $("#tabs").click(function(){
           $(this).click(function(){
              alert(this); 
           });
   });
</script>


<style type="text/css">
#navbarID li {
    display: inline;
}
</style>


</head>  
<body>  

<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
             <li><a href="type1.html">Type 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="type2.html">Type 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="type3.html">Type 3</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed your code formatting for you, but you should probably consider adding your question to the body of the post.

Comment: Please use the title for a _summary_ of your problem, not for the entire problem text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the html should be something like this.

```
<ul id='tabs'>
<li><a href='type1.html'>Type 1</a></li>
<li><a href='type2.html'>Type 2</a></li>
<li><a href='type3.html'>Type 3</a></li>
<li><a href='type4.html'>Type 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

the css part could be this:

```
    ul#tabs { list-style: none; }
    ul#tabs li { display: inline; }
```

the onclick that you want on jQuery is like this:

```
 $('ul#tabs li a').click(function(){ alert('i was clicked!'); return false; });
```

Comment: Reigel ...your code did the job. Thank you so very much! Also Bean suggested I add this: alert("U selected: "+$(this).html());  ...to tell me which menu item was selected. They all worked perfect. Thanks to you both. sonny5

Answer (score 0):

`alert($(this).html());` will tell you what the contents of that nav item are.
   Maybe you should use `<span>` instead of `<div>` for inline.

Comment: you're making the one who asked more confused.